# Can not undo xcode changes after building

Tags: xcode

Simple but annoying bug, I can't undo my changes once I run my project. Before running I can undo (command + z), but after running I get [mac error sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rz44o_gGpE) when I try to undo.

I'm using xcode 12.2 but it was happening in other versions too.
I deleted user data, cleaned build folders but no luck.

What could it be?

I am using macbook pro 2019 os version is catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you have a build phase that modifies your files, like `SwiftFormat`. Make sure this is not the case.

Comment: Can u plz describe this in brief, bcz I'm facing same issue